# Parallels Webmail issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtpclient

I know maybe my question is some strange but I want to send email from asp.net web project to my registered clients. I can do this using gmail so easily. but I want send it from `Parallels Webmail`. 
my C# code is like this:

```
using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("info@mydomain.com", email))
            {
                mm.Subject = "Account Activation";
                string body = "Hello " + name.Trim();
                mm.Body = body;
                mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "mydomain.com";
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential("info@mydomain.com", "mypassword");
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
                smtp.Port = 26;//587 is also tested
                smtp.Send(mm);
        }
```

But I get error "`A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 74.63.251.194:26`"

I am sure I can't send right smtp.host format.
this is only setting for email client on paralles[image]

**The screen shot of error message is here too**:[image]

***Any comments are appreciated.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use port 25 and make `smtp.EnableSsl = true;`

```
using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("info@mydomain.com", email))
{
    mm.Subject = "Account Activation";
    string body = "Hello " + name.Trim();
    mm.Body = body;
    mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.EnableSsl = false;
    smtp.Host = "mydomain.com";
    NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential("info@mydomain.com", "mypassword");
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
    smtp.Port = 25;
    smtp.Send(mm);
}
```

Comment: @RezaPaidar remove `        smtp.EnableSsl = true;` and try

Comment: again send me "Server does not support secure connections."

Comment: then try again make `smtp.EnableSsl = false;` because every way here is working

Comment: yes. You was Right. It's worked. But for first time my email will go to spam folder because of port 25. is there anyway to use ssl method to more security and not spaming?